# How can I modify this recursion function to print out letters in specific order

Tags: ruby, recursion

I was just going through some interview recursion questions and one was print out a subset of a set. This is my code in ruby

```
def subset(arr, ifTrue, element, size)
  if element == 0
    ifTrue[element] = true
    print "{ "
    ifTrue.each_with_index { |item, index| print arr[index] if item === true }
    print " }\n"
    ifTrue[element] = false
    print "{ "
    ifTrue.each_with_index { |item, index| print arr[index] if item === true }
    print " }\n"
  else
    ifTrue[element] = false
    subset(arr, ifTrue, element - 1, size)
    ifTrue[element] = true
    subset(arr, ifTrue, element - 1, size)
  end
end

arr = ['A','B','C']
ifTrue = Array.new(arr.size,false)

subset(arr, ifTrue, 2, arr.size)
```

The output is correct

```
{ A }
{  }
{ AB }
{ B }
{ AC }
{ C }
{ ABC }
{ BC }
```

but I was wondering how could I modify it so it prints it in a better order such as

```
{  }
{ A }
{ B }
{ C }
{ AB }
{ AC }
{ BC }
{ ABC }
```

without queues/sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build the set of subsets recursively as well, so you can sort it as you wish later:

```
def subset(arr, ifTrue, element, size, subsets)
  if element == 0
    ifTrue[element] = true
    ss = []
    ifTrue.each_with_index { |item, index| ss << arr[index] if item === true }
    subsets << ss
    ss = []
    ifTrue[element] = false
    ifTrue.each_with_index { |item, index| ss << arr[index] if item === true }
    subsets << ss
  else
    ifTrue[element] = false
    subset(arr, ifTrue, element - 1, size, subsets)
    ifTrue[element] = true
    subset(arr, ifTrue, element - 1, size, subsets)
  end
end

arr = ['A','B','C']
ifTrue = Array.new(arr.size,false)

subsets = []
subset(arr, ifTrue, 2, arr.size, subsets)
puts (subsets.sort { |x,y| x.count <=> y.count }).to_s
```

Output:

```
$ ruby subset.rb 
# [[], ["A"], ["B"], ["C"], ["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["B", "C"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
```

**EDIT**

To output the text exactly as you want, replace the last line where `puts` is called with the following:

```
subsets = subsets.sort { |x,y| x.count <=> y.count }

subsets.each do |subset|
    str = "{ "
    subset.each { |x| str << x }
    str << " }"
    puts str
end
```

Here's the output:

```
$ ruby subset.rb 
{  }
{ A }
{ B }
{ C }
{ AB }
{ AC }
{ BC }
{ ABC }
```